# Making a jar that accepts names and values on command line

Tags: java, jar, command-line-arguments, name-value

Relevant Links:

[Java: Passing combination of named and unnamed parameters to executable Jar/Main Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891990/java-passing-combination-of-named-and-unnamed-parameters-to-executable-jar-main)

[Passing arguments to JAR which is required by Java Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5536476/passing-arguments-to-jar-which-is-required-by-java-interpreter)

I understand how to pass strings from the command line to execute my main method:

`java -jar myApp.jar "argument1"`

My question is: is it possible to set up my main method in a way that would accept:

`java -jar myApp.jar -parameter1 "argument1"`

Here is my simple main method for context if you need it

```
public class myApp {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        System.out.println("Argument1: "+args[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This related question will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/367714/2127492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is: whatever you pass on the command line goes into that *args* array. To be precise:

```
java xxx -jar JAR yyy
```

xxx: would be arguments to the JVM itself, like -Dprop:value for *properties*

yyy: are passed as arguments to *your* main method

So, when you pass "-parameter 'argument1'" then ... that is what you will see inside main!

In other words: the idea that some command line strings are "arguments"; and other are "-switches", or "--flags", or "-h" shortcuts ... you simply have to write the code to do all of that.

Luckily, there are plenty of libraries out there that help with that; see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments-in-java)

Comment: thanks, so really the only way to do this is to manage the input in my main method?

Comment: See my latest update ... basically: yes. But you dont have to write that code your own. There are libraries that help with that!